# Site is separate height from BODY/HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to fix an issue where the site is longer than the HTML and BODY, with no float elements that may extend it. It also is getting an even larger height when mousing over a dropdown menu.

The site is located at https://www.librassay.com/, you should be able to see the large footer, and watch the sidebar extend when mousing over the "Categories" dropdown.

As far as I can tell no elements are receiving any javascript alterations, its just some odd issues with how the browser is rendering it. So maybe a HTML structural issue? I've been racking my head against this, so any insight is greatly appreciated.

I'm using Chrome 22.0, if that helps.

Comment: I looked at it, and I have a feeling it might be caused by your script at the end. Do you have any other place you can set it, or are you forced to have it there. If not, try putting it in the header, see if the problem still exists. I cant detect any changes in the css when I load the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.largelogo` negative margin causes it

Comment: @Yaroslav In fact **it is** the answer to the question. There is no "critique or request clarification" in this answer…

Comment: @feela, both of you are right, missunderstood the answer. Deleted the comment and upvoted

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixes the large footer. The dropdown is still extending the page height though, any ideas as to why that's happening?

Comment: I didn't write this, unfortunately. Picking up someone else's mess is not my favorite, but projects are projects.

Comment: hate to bother again, but the dropdown menu is still extending the height of the page when its shorter than the screen. I've removed all negative margin, and the footer height is removed as well. Any guess?

Comment: my guess because of long navigation block under others section, but I can't really spend more time at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a somewhat different experience. In IE there is no change in the document size. In Firefox the document gets smaller instead of larger when hovering the button.

You have some invalid markup that you should fix. There is for example a `div` element inside a `span` element. That would typically give different results in different browsers, as each browser has its own way of trying to fix invalid markup.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.librassay.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0